How to manage transaction when testing JPA application
I have a server application which interacts with a database via JPA. Methods in this application usually look like this:
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
try {
  // do some work
  entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
  entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
}

I need to write tests for each of these methods. I would like to be able to undo any changes made in the tested method so the database is in the same state at the start of every test.
My first thought was to do this in my test method:
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
myMethod();
entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();

but that causes java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction already active when the tested method calls begin().
So then I commented out the begin() line of the tested method. Then I get org.hibernate.TransactionException: Cannot rollback transaction in current status [COMMITTED] on the line where I rollback the transaction after the tested method call.
So I removed the commit() from the tested method. This makes the test work, but when the actual application runs this method, the changes don't persist. In addition, the id field of my entity is not set after entityManager.persist(myEntity), which is important for creating entities which reference other entities.
I tried using the @Transactional annotation in several places including on the test class, the test method, and the tested method (and every permutation of those I could think of). It would get the test to work, but not the application.
I know I could manually undo the changes I expect to see after the tested method is called, but this would be not only tedious but error prone and brittle as the tested method could change to modify other data in the database and the test method might not be updated.
My application uses javaee-api 8.0.1, and the persistence provider is hibernate.

Mockito
I think this might be a good case to use something like Mockito, that way you don't actually interact with the DB. If you want to test how different entities interact, you can use Mockito to return some object in an expected state and then interact with that entity, instead of actually creating it in the database. You can also use Mockito to validate transactional behaviour.
Mockito.when(myRepository.read(Mockito.any()).thenReturn(desiredEntity);

In-Memory Database
Alternatively, as a part of the test, spin up a database that stores the objects in-memory. This way, you're not impacting other data, and you don't need to worry about cleaning it up.
I hope that helps a little.

Mocking the entity manager was my original approach, but I realized an issue. With EntityManager there are always multiple ways to do something. You can get an entity by entityManager.find or you can use entityManager.createQuery. If somebody changes the code later to use a different approach that does the same thing the test would be broken even though the code is still functional. It should test the effect of the code, not the implementation.

And the problem I have with using an in memory database is that we are using postgres, which doesn't have an in-memory version. Using an in-memory db would mean I couldn't test methods that use postgres specific features. I'm not sure if my company uses any postgres specific features currently, but there's no guarantee they won't want to eventually.

Yeah that is a fair point about testing the effects of the code and not the implementation. The only other idea that comes to mind is to spin up a Postgres container, that way you're testing the effects of your code, not impacting existing data, and it should be usable both locally, and in a pipeline if needed.
